# Modifing entity to the context in EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a entity with a list of another entity.

```
 public virtual List<PeopleAddress> Addresses{ get; set; }
```

In edit this entity, users can add new Address to AddressList.

In post method:

```
 _db.Entry(people).State = EntityState.Modified;
 _db.SaveChanges();
```

That `people.Addresses` have 4 records. 2 record is saved in PeopleAddress but Two new records have been added that have Id=0.

in  `EntityState.Modified` get error :

```
Attaching an entity of type 'Web.Models.PeopleAddress' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.
```

My question is :

The EF can not add records?
Should i add new records manually before edit People?

Answer (score 0):

The exception message already told you what to do:

> This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. **In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.**

In other words, you need to make sure that each new `PeopleAddress` has a state of `Added` and not `Modified` when you call `SaveChanges`.  Something like this should work

```
_db.People.Add(people);
_db.Entry(people).State = EntityState.Modified;

foreach(PeopleAddress address in newAdddresses) {
    _db.Entry(address).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
}
```

Comment: Tanks, I use this, i don't get error but add all Address.(address that added before and new address)

Comment: You'll need to mark old addresses as unchanged, see my edit.  You need a way to identify which addresses are new and which are old so you can mark the old ones as unchanged.

Comment: Thanks, but when i use this i get error : `Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.`